How can I send data over Bluetooth from a website (made with React jsx) to a raspberry pi?
I've tried to use web bluetooth to set up communication to send data from my website to my raspberry pi zero 2 w so that it can activate/deactivate some motors for a project. I haven't found any good documentation on this and need help. On a side note, would it be possible to open a socket over bluetooth to send data instead?
Ideally I would be sending a sequence of 4 numbers from my website to the raspberrypi to decode into instructions.
I've tried to use the Web bluetooth api, bluez, and looked at setting up a socket, but nothing I've tried so far has had any sucess.

do you want to communicate on front end or back end?

Web Bluetooth is Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and Bluetooth sockets is Bluetooth Classic so they won't communicate with each other. You will need to create BLE peripheral device on your RPi. e.g. https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I was trying to communicate from the front end in the jsx but I don't believe that works so I tried to set up a backend to communicate with the pi but that wasn't working.

In order to create a better development experience and entice developers to create more complex web applications that use Web Bluetooth, an internal user interface hosted at chrome://bluetooth-internals for monitoring Bluetooth activity and devices was created. You should be able to find and inspect the device you are trying connect to using web bluetooth. This will help you prove that the Bluetooth peripheral device is working as required.
